# "of the feudal Estates type" or "of the feudal-Estates type"?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation

In [one Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zemsky_Sobor) I read this definition:

> The zemsky sobor was the first Russian
>   parliament of ***the feudal Estates
>   type***, in the 16th and 17th
>   centuries.

I don't understand, why is there no hyphen between ***feudal*** and ***Estates***? Is there any rule that would regulate the usage of hyphens in such cases?

Comment: Related: [To hyphenate or not?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11570/to-hyphenate-or-not), [When is it appropriate to use a hyphen?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12494/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-a-hyphen), [When to use a hyphen in writing a compound word](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word).

Comment: Thank you, RegDwight. I should have researched more before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of a hyphen in this case is not clear-cut, and there isn't a rule which *absolutely* dictates what should be done in this scenario.

*To me*, at least, the quoted text is difficult to understand. I would have put in a hyphen.

Comment: Whereas to me, the hyphenated text is difficult to understand (because I'm now looking for a non-standard meaning, because I'm like that :-).  There's no clear winner, as you say.