# Hyphenating “steady state”

Tags: nouns, adjectives, hyphenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it appropriate to use a hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12494/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-a-hyphen)

I am unsure if and when to hyphenate **steady state** (in a mathematical context), i.e.:

> We now calculate the steady-state concentration from the given formula.

I looked at [this generic hyphenation question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word), but the links given there did not give a clear rule for this case.

To me, it seems most natural to write:

> This is the steady state described by the formula.

But, at the same time:

> This is the steady-state concentration described by the formula.

That is, hyphenate if it describes another noun but not if it stands on its own. Does that make sense? [Searching for books on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_scat_283155_ln?rh=n:283155,k:steady-state&keywords=steady-state&ie=UTF8&qid=1307642591&scn=283155&h=25716a064e837c168c6d7f808f3dff5a2447bba4#/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=stripbooks&field-keywords=steady%20state&rh=n:283155,k:steady%20state) brings up titles with both **steady state** and **steady-state** which seem to at least partially conform to this rule.

Or would it be better to just chose either hyphenation or no hyphenation and then stick to that consistently?

Comment: Perhaps you weren't looking at the right generic question. (^_^) How about these: [To hyphenate or not?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11570/to-hyphenate-or-not), [When is it appropriate to use a hyphen?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12494/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-a-hyphen).

Comment: @RegDwight: Hmm I didn't see those. Guess I need to brush up on my searching skills. Thanks a lot for the links!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Steady is an adjective which modifies state in all these cases. So where state is the noun, there should be no hyphen. Where steady and state are used as a single adjective - a [compound modifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier) - for another noun (concentration, in your first example) they should be hyphenated.

In other words, your instinct is correct.