# Should I use a hyphen in "patient tailored" vs "patient-tailored"?

Tags: hyphenation, science, academia

Being a non-native English speaker, I was wondering which is most correct?

(1) Patient-tailored staging of xx carcinoma, or
(2) Patient tailored staging of xx carcinoma?

It is for a scientific paper.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hyphenation in compound adjectives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39273/hyphenation-in-compound-adjectives). Here, the novel(ish) compound adjective needs the hyphen to show that it is a single lexeme (this is not always the case) because (b) it is fairly novel / unusual, and hyphenation is usual if not universal, but (a) because here the reading of 'patient' as an individual lexeme is quite understandable, giving at least a garden-path situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is correct. You want the two words to function as an adjective describing the 'staging', so you need to join them together with the hyphen.

Comment: Yes. Any pre-positioned adjectival collocation, involving two or more nouns should be hyphenated. At least that is the current style demanded in most UK universities, at this time.

Comment: @WS2 'tailored' is a verb-form.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ok - a noun-verb collocation then!