# Hyphenating adjectives

Tags: hyphenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To hyphenate or not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11570/to-hyphenate-or-not)
>   [When is it appropriate to use a hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12494/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-a-hyphen)

In the phrase

> It is simply a large door sized wall of fire.

Should "door sized" be hyphenated to "door-sized"?