# Nonionic or non-ionic?

Tags: hyphenation, prefixes, negative-prefixes

which is more correct or more frequently used? Nonionic or non-ionic (polymers)? It´s for an academic presentation.

Comment: Have you checked your style guide? (It's very relevant since some style guides specify how certain expressions should be written or which dictionary you should use to help spell words.)

Comment: Similar: [Can there be a hyphen in “nonlinear”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32428)

Comment: Even if the answer isn't in a journal style guide (seems unlikely @Laurel). just download pdf articles from the journal you wish to publish in and search them for nonionic and non-ionic. Either go with the majority or if there is a split, make your own choice, perhaps on your respect for the authors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can there be a hyphen in "nonlinear"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32428/can-there-be-a-hyphen-in-nonlinear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that ***nonionic*** is more common than ***non-ionic*** according to [Google's ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nonionic%2Cnon-ionic&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnonionic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnon%20-%20ionic%3B%2Cc0):

[image: Google ngram for nonionic and non-ionic]

Comment: Interesting, and you answered the question in a way, but as a practicing and publishing scientist I would always write non-ionic (e.g. detergent) in a biological science journal. So the advice in the comment — to check the usage in your field — would seem to be more pertintent. Google ngram checks books, not scientific journals.

Answer (score 0):

Merriam-Webster spells it in the closed-form [**nonionic**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonionic).

On the other hand, Oxford spells it in the hyphenated form [**non-ionic**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/non-ionic), while also providing the closed-form [**nonionic**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/nonionic) as being *US English*.

So, if you go by the dictionaries (or by a style guide that says to use a regional dictionary), use **nonionic** for a US audience and **non-ionic** for a UK audience.

Having said that, although the British corpus on [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nonionic%2Cnon-ionic&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnonionic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnon%20-%20ionic%3B%2Cc0) shows that **non-ionic** is slightly more common in print in general, between 1989 and 1998 (for some reason), **nonionic** was actually used more often.

[image]

Comment: As a scientist I would give no credence to the 89-98 results. You'd need to look at examples to find out what is causeing the obvious anomaly.