# How should one punctuate “upper right most”?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation, compound-adjectives

For *upper right most*, I’ve seen it written *upper-right most*, *upper-right-most*, and with no hyphens at all.

What makes the most sense to me is *upper rightmost*, but it’s hard to tell that *upper right* is the adjective to which *most* is being applied.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using "non-" to prefix a two-word phrase](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78050/using-non-to-prefix-a-two-word-phrase)

Comment: _Rightmost_ is already unhyphenated. There need be no hyphens at all. I.e, _upper rightmost_ is kosher.

Comment: *Upper rightmost* is not the same as *upper-right most*, so it may depend on which you mean.

Comment: @JohnLawler: That makes a lot of sense; I wish it were clearer to read.

Comment: Then don't use such small phrases. If you've got a sentence worth of meaning, send a sentence to do it; don't try to pack it into one teensy phrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As John Lawler comments, and as this chart makes clear,...

[image]

...***rightmost*** isn't normally hyphenated. And there's no need for one in [***upper rightmost***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22upper%20rightmost%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl).

Comment: This is not a valid Google N-Gram: the one for `right-most` is actually using a binary minus to subtract incidences of *most* from those of *right*. [See here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/info#advanced).

Comment: @tchrist: I don't think so. It says **Replaced right-most with right - most to match how we processed the books.** That would be pretty daft if it was just doing arithmetic (which I thought always required brackets anyway).

Comment: Then why doesn’t it supply a Google Books link to texts with *right-most* in them?

Comment: @tchrist: I didn't notice any **right-most** instances in the first 2-3 pages. It only has the non-hyphenated one in the "link to books" lines under the chart. I assume that's because there weren't enough of the hyphenated one, but I don't know much about how NGrams works internally. I trust what the chart is telling me, though.