# non-living vs nonliving

Tags: orthography

What is the proper way to spell this word? This in the context of writing a curriculum for children distinguishing living vs non-living things. Is it `non-living` or `nonliving`?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26837/is-the-use-of-a-hyphen-between-non-and-an-adjective-strictly-necessary

Comment: Use non-living only where the negation takes the focus.

Comment: Perhaps worth adding, though, that *in general* "non" is hyphenated: non-smoking, non-stop, non-Newtonian fluid.

Comment: @DavidGarner Yes, but on the question linked above, there are also examples given without hyphentation: nonnegative, nonmagnetic, nonferrous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both are widely used, dictionaries seem to lean towards **nonliving**.

- [oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nonliving)
- [merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/nonliving)

[image]

Also found this link, which may be of use for your curriculum ([PBS](http://www.pbslearningmedia.org/resource/tdc02.sci.life.colt.lp_living/living-vs-nonliving/)).