# nonclassical vs. non-classical

Tags: orthography, hyphenation, accent

I've seen both spellings many times, i.e. on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-classical_analysis), [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/nonclassical) and [dozens of papers](https://scholar.google.nl/scholar?hl=nl&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=non-classical+%7C+nonclassical&btnG=). I was wondering if there is a difference between US, Canadian, Australian and British spelling or if you can just use whatever you prefer?

*(There was no good search engine result on this and it took me too long to figure out, hence this Q&A.)*

Comment: "Nonclassical" is the non-classical version.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently both spellings are equally okay and are not connected to certain regions or accents.

[Literature analysis](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Non-classical%2CNonclassical&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CNon%20-%20classical%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnon%20-%20classical%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNon%20-%20Classical%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNon%20-%20classical%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnon%20-%20Classical%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CNonclassical%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnonclassical%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNonclassical%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNONCLASSICAL%3B%2Cc0) seems to agree with this assessment:
[image: Use of <code>non-classical</code> vs <code>nonclassical</code>]

Sources:

- [Is the use of a hyphen between "non" and an adjective strictly necessary?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26837/is-the-use-of-a-hyphen-between-non-and-an-adjective-strictly-necessary)
- [non-living vs nonliving](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227914/non-living-vs-nonliving)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your insight, we at EL&U appreciate the effort.