# Sidenote, side-note, Side Note or Side note

Tags: meaning, word-choice, orthography

So I've thought of a name for something, but cannot decide on how I should write it. In School, I vaguely remember someone saying "when you want to say something as one word, when it's really two words, then you hyphenate them", which leads me to believe I should be writing it like "Side-note". But How should you really write it, when it is going to be the name of something?

Are Sidenote, Side-note, and Side Note all correct? Which version should I use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [To hyphenate or not?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11570/to-hyphenate-or-not). I actually think this is Not Constructive, since there's no absolute rule about which pairings can be joined into a single word or hyhenated, and it's pointless having "votes" here about each specific case. Follow a style guide if you have one, or search Google Books and copy whatever the majority do. Or just make your own decision.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: So, basically what you're saying is that neither of the choices in my question are incorrect? Also, I don't care about the voting system, or what the majority of others are doing, I care about using the correct version, and if none of them are incorrect, then you could've just said so, and used that as an answer.

Comment: That wasn't *exactly* what I meant, but after following my own advice, I'll just note that ["as a side note"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22as+a+side+note%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is about 30 times more common in Google Books than the single-word version. GB indexes hyphens as spaces, but if you follow that link I think you'll agree most people *don't* hyphenate it. I don't actually understand why you're including variable capitalisation here.

Comment: @F: Looks like three versions of title case to me. There's actually a 4th: "Side-Note", and whether this one or "Side-note" is "correct" is a matter of which style manual is used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Sidenote for Mac"](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/17654/sidenote)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Merriam-Webster's 3rd Unabridged:

> Main Entry : sidenote
>   Function:noun
>   : a note of reference that is set in the side margin or a page usually in smaller type than the text

This is standard American English.