# Awkwardness around 'go live' phrase

Tags: phrases, adjectives, compound-adjectives

Context: software company training documents.

We commonly use the phrase "go live" when talking about making a system operational. I'm fine with using it as two separate words, but it becomes awkward when it's an adjective. E.g. *Preparing for your go live transition.* Am I focusing on this too much, or is that potentially confusing? I've seen this phrase written as go live, go-live, Go Live, and Go-Live (all in one Microsoft article, actually). I'd appreciate some opinions.

Comment: Of course it's potentially confusing.  Why not just say *preparing for your **launch***?  I'm on your side, but as is, this is Not Constructive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [To hyphenate or not?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11570/to-hyphenate-or-not)

Comment: Just came here to say this phrase irks me (somewhat irrationally, I concede). Why not just say launch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be treated like any other multi-word phrase. Use two words when it's a noun phrase:

> The go live will be this weekend

And a hyphen when it's an adjectival phrase:

> We're preparing for your go-live transition.

Now, unless *Go Live* or *Go-Live* is a proper name, I don't see any reason it should be capitalized.

Comment: Thank you both for your input. I've been told by a coworker that 'launch' doesn't quite convey what we're doing (transitioning from a sandbox environment to an operational system). I think I may have to put my aversion aside and treat this word as described in this answer.

Comment: @Greg Williams: Whatever you do, it will always be somewhat awkward. You're trying to force a *phrasal verb* (go live) into an adjectival role. English is pretty flexible, and will bend a lot without breaking, but asking for a "correct" way to do something like this is effectively a fool's errand.

Answer (score -1):

The word **activate** would convey the intent and I would encourage you to use it.

Consistency in terminology as a defense only goes so far and I don't believe it will be enough to earn your audience's forgiveness for using a phrase like "the go live" or "your go live"

> Preparing for your software/website activation