# Using 'already' before adjectives

Tags: word-choice

Is the usage of the word 'already' in the following sentence correct?

> We have used an already calibrated camera fixed on the robot.

Comment: It's fine but you need to hyphenate. A better choice would be "pre-calibrated"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this usage is correct. Note that it is conventional to use a hyphen when you are writing a compound adjective (see rule 6.39 given in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/11622/43004), which draws from *CMoS*):

> already-calibrated camera

As you are probably aware, this means the same thing as:

> We have used a camera that has already been calibrated, fixed on the robot.

---

Here are some examples from [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) that use "already" to modify an adjective in this way:

[*already-established*](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/x3.asp?xx=1&w11=already-established&r=)

> If your own novel's hero seems too similar to an *already-established* sleuth, try some mixing and matching.

[*already-existing*](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/x3.asp?xx=2&w11=already-existing&r=)

> This article focuses on one *already-existing* version of what new schools might look like and explores some problems it faces in contemporary America.

[*already-mastered*](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/x3.asp?xx=3&w11=already-mastered&r=)

> Curriculum compacting was designed to eliminate *already-mastered* content and to provide students with enrichment activities in the time saved.

Comment: A well-crafted answer!